# Select always returns data

Tags: c, sockets, select

I am reading from two sockets using select, and I am sending only one message from each socket.  The select never seems to timeout, but always returns either 1 or 2 with the same message over and over.  I am resetting the select parameters each time I go through the while loop.

Here is my code:

```
while(1)
{
    FD_ZERO(&master); 
    for (i = 0; i < fdmax; i++)
    {
        FD_SET(sock_list[i], &master); 
    }
    tv.tv_sec = 1; 
    tv.tv_usec = 300; 

    int sel = select(fdmax, &master, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    if (sel > 0)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < fdmax; i++)
        {
            if (FD_ISSET(i, &master))
            {
                recv_msg(i, buf); 
                print("msg from %d: %s %d  %d\n", i, buf, sel, tv.tv_sec); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone see a problem with my select?

Comment: The problem is more likely in `recv_msg` because it seems you never (fully) read the data: hence `select` tells you there's data available

Comment: did you check that recv_msg works?

Comment: You don't check the return value of `recv_msg`. Check if the socket is closed or if there is a read error. Close those sockets, and remove them from your list.

Comment: what is recv_msg()? should'n it take sock_list[i] as argument instead of i ?

Comment: You've not shown the contents of `sock_list` or the value of `fdmax`, so we can't easily say whether there's something wrong.  Note that disk files never cause `select()` to wait.  You've not shown any diagnostic printing.  I think you've got a crucial mismatch between `FD_SET` and `FD_ISSET`.  I am also deeply suspicious that `fdmax` is 2 but the socket descriptors are both larger than that.

Answer (score 1):

the first parameter to select() is one higher than the highest socket value, NOT a count of the number of socket values +1.

It is 'ok' to write the first parameter as:

```
select( FD_SETSIZE+1, .... );
```

this line:

```
if (FD_ISSET(i, &master))
```

does not check the right thing Suggest:

```
if (FD_ISSET( sock_list[i], &master))
```